# Reverse a input String and words in o/p need to be separate with space as per length of each keyword in input

Tags: java, string, reverse

For example:

```
subex is in bangalore
```

o/p:

```
erola gn ab nisixebus
```

I tried using `StringBuffer` to use the reverse method, but this will just simply reverse the sentence. I need to add white space to the reversed sentence exactly at the same positions the input had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way, use `StringBuilder.reverse()` method:

```
    String input = "subex is in bangalore";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.replace(" ", "")).reverse();
    int index = input.indexOf(" ");
    while (index >= 0) {
        result.replace(index, index, " ");
        index = input.indexOf(" ", index + 1);          
    }
```

Comment: result  will contain a extra space in the end, which can be easily removed by trim() .  ` result.toString().trim(); `

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way in this case. You need to process each character one by one.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length());

int end = input.length() - 1;

for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    if(input.charAt(i) == ' '){
       builder.append(' ');
    }else{
       while(input.charAt(end) == ' ')
           end--;
       builder.append(input.charAt(end--));
    }
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: You're missing a bit of bounds checking here. Also, nit: instantiate the builder using `input.length()`, so it never has to resize its internal char array.

Comment: @AndyTurner You mean bounds for `end` ?, I think it is not necessary :) Thanks for the `input.length()` btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class test
{    
static void reverseString(String inputString)
{
    char[] inputArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    char[] resultArray = new char[inputArray.length];
    //insert spaces at required positions
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) 
    {
        if (inputArray[i] == ' ') 
        {
            resultArray[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    int j = resultArray.length-1;
    //copy every non-space character of inputArray at 'j' position of resultArray
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray[i] != ' ') 
        {
            //If resultArray already has space at index j then decrementing 'j'
            if(resultArray[j] == ' ')
            {
                j--;
            }
            resultArray[j] = inputArray[i];

            j--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(inputString+" ---> "+String.valueOf(resultArray));
}
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        reverseString("subex is in bangalore");
   }
}
```

Output:

`subex is in bangalore ---> erola gn ab nisixebus`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Store the positions of spaces.

Step 2: Remove all spaces from the given string.

Step 3: Reverse the string

Step 4: add whitespace character at the places stored before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also..

`public static void main(String[] args) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("subex is in bangalore");
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         char a[] = sb.toString().toCharArray();
         char b[] = (sb.reverse().toString()).replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
         for(int i = 0, j=0; i<sb.toString().length();i++, j++){

         if(a[i]== ' '){
            sb1.append(" ");
            j--;
          }
          else
            sb1.append(b[j]);

            if (j==b.length-1)
                break;
         }
         System.out.println(sb1.toString().trim());
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Normal char array swapping way,

```
String input = "subex is in bangalore";
char[] array = input.toCharArray();
int len = array.length - 1;

for(int idx1 = 0, rev = 0, idx2 = len - rev; idx1 < idx2; idx1++, rev++, idx2 = len - rev) {
    if(array[idx1] == ' ') 
        ++idx1;

    if(array[idx2] == ' ')
        --idx2;

    char c = array[idx1];
    array[idx1] = array[idx2];
    array[idx2] = c;
}

System.out.println(array); // o/p: erola gn ab nisixebus
```